# Using localStorage in Javascript to show modal only to new users or to the users returning after 30 minutes

Tags: javascript, local-storage

As the question sounds, I have a popup modal on every html page of my website. I want to show that modal to the users who are new to my web site or to the users who has already visited my website and visiting again after 30 minute session. I want to do it with localStorage in JS (no JQuery).

Here is the JS code -

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const modal = document.querySelector(".modal");
const closeButton = document.querySelector(".close-button");
const skipOptinForm = document.querySelector(".skip-optin-form-text");
let isOpened = false;

function updateModalSession() {
    localStorage.setItem("visitTime", getTimestampSeconds());
}
function getTimestampSeconds() { // Returns the unix timestamp in seconds
    var time_stamp = 0;
    if(time_stamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)){}
    else
        time_stamp = Math.floor(new Date().getTime()  / 1000);
    
    return time_stamp;
}
function getModalShowPermission() {
    var currentTimeStamp = getTimestampSeconds();
    var storedTimeStamp =  parseInt(localStorage.getItem("visitTime"));
    
    if(localStorage.getItem("visitTime") == "null") {
        console.log("New User. modal show permision granted");
        return true;
    } else if((currentTimeStamp - storedTimeStamp) >= 1800) {
        console.log("Returning User after 30 mins session. modal show permision granted");
        return true;
    } else {
        console.log("Not new nor returning after 30 mins session. modal show permision denied");
        return false;
    }
}
const openModal = () => {
    if(getModalShowPermission() == true) {
        updateModalSession();
        modal.classList.add("is-open");
        body.style.overflow = "hidden";
    }   
};

const closeModal = () => {
  modal.classList.remove("is-open");
  body.style.overflow = "initial";
};

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  if (window.scrollY > window.innerHeight / 3 && !isOpened) {
    isOpened = true;
    openModal();
  }
});
closeButton.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
skipOptinForm.addEventListener("click", closeModal);
document.onkeydown = evt => {
  evt = evt || window.event;
  evt.keyCode === 27 ? closeModal() : false;
};
```

The code working fine for returning users but it is not working for new users. The above code isn't showing modal to the new users.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in first if clause -

`if(localStorage.getItem("visitTime") == "null")`

The if condition should be -

`if(localStorage.getItem("visitTime") == null)`

`localStorage.getItem(key)` returns *null* when key isn't available in Storage

and,

`localStorage.getItem(key)` returns *String* when key is available in Storage

Comment: Hey Varun I did a bit of formatting on your answer. Whenever you include code, try to use `code fencing` instead of **bold** or *italics* to distinguish from the non-code parts.

Answer (score 0):

There is a clean way of using the local and session storage with an expiry time that you can find here : [enter link description here](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/javascript-localstorage-with-ttl-expiry/)

Basicaly you want to save your data with an expiry date :

```
function setWithExpiry(key, value, ttl) {
    const now = new Date()

    // `item` is an object which contains the original value
    // as well as the time when it's supposed to expire
    const item = {
        value: value,
        expiry: now.getTime() + ttl,
    }
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(item))
}
```

and then access it by checking if the expiry date is outdated :

```
function getWithExpiry(key) {
    const itemStr = localStorage.getItem(key)
    // if the item doesn't exist, return null
    if (!itemStr) {
        return null
    }
    const item = JSON.parse(itemStr)
    const now = new Date()
    // compare the expiry time of the item with the current time
    if (now.getTime() > item.expiry) {
        // If the item is expired, delete the item from storage
        // and return null
        localStorage.removeItem(key)
        return null
    }
    return item.value
}
```